# Would this simple code cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-leaks, virtual, destructor

Say you have the following C++ code snippet:

```
class base {};
class derived : public base {
public:
    std::string str;
};

int main() {
    base *b = new derived();
    delete b;
}
```

This would leak, right? `derived`'s string's destructor is never being called because `base`'s destructor isn't marked as virtual. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are `delete`-ing a derived through a pointer of type `base*`, and `base` does not have a `virtual` destructor.

That is [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), which means anything may happen.

While causing a memory-leak if the `std::string` has allocated any memory (think short-string-optimization, which would mean no extra memory needs to be allocated for an empty string), is one possible (and a quite likely) manifestation of UB, that's not the worst that could happen.

Comment: Okay, so most of the time it would cause a memory leak. Is it still UB if the derived class has only POD members?

Comment: You mean members with trivial destructors? Yes, that does not change anything.

Comment: @BWG: Undefined behaviour is not "mostly defined behaviour". It's undefined, and not usually worth debating. You will only get a correct program if you do things whose results are defined.

Comment: @BWG: You misunderstand. You don't need virtual destructors just because you are inheriting. You only need them if you destroy a more-derived object *through a pointer to a base subobject*. Many, if not most, applications of class inheritance never need this.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok, yeah I see that. I just feel like situations like the one in my question come up EXTREMELY often, and i've never had the slightest clue how catastrophic it is. Makes me question all the other stuff i'm doing.

Comment: @BWG: Well, feelings are subjective. I'd say that it's actually rather seldom that I need to manage a class hierarchy dynamically, i.e. that I cannot know the actual types until runtime. And even if that happens, some form of ad-hoc type erasure a la `std::function` or `boost::any` usually solves the problem better than a hand-rolled polymorphic hierarchy. Of course I don't know what your codebase looks like and what your needs are, but my general advice would be to use runtime polymorphism sparingly, and preferably never in public.

Comment: @BWG that's why browsing StackOverflow is useful, you find out about all those things you assumed were fine but actually aren't

Comment: @KerrekSB Wait, are you advising to avoid using polymorphism? And trust me, you wouldn't want to even look at my "code base".

Comment: @BWG: Yes, provided we are talking about dynamic polymorphism, and specifically dynamic allocation of objects of polymorphic type and managing through their common base. It may be necessary occasionally, but not ubiquitously, and often ready-made solutions exist. And I trust you.